# Pivot not updating programmatically

Tags: unity

I have a canvas.  It has an empty game object as a child.  That object has a RectTransform component.  The RectTransform pivot value is set to 0.4, 0.5 (x, y).
In some code I wanted to update the pivot value using the following:

```
Debug.Log(((RectTransform)transform).pivot);  // logs: (0.4, 0.5)
((RectTransform)transform).pivot.Set(0.3f, 0.8f);
Debug.Log(((RectTransform)transform).pivot);  // logs: (0.4, 0.5)
```

I don't know why the set command is not working.  The tooltip for `Set` is: "Set x and y components of an existing Vector2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
((RectTransform)transform).pivot = new Vector2(0.3f, 0.8f);
```

The tool tip for `.Set` is correct that it mutates the Vector2.  But the `.pivot` is a getter and because Vector2 is a struct it means `.pivot` returns a **copy** of the Vector2, not a reference.

If you wanted to use `.Set` then you'd need to use:

```
var new_pivot = ((RectTransform)transform).pivot.Set(0.3f, 0.8f);
((RectTransform)transform).pivot = new_pivot;
```

Comment: `.Set` is indeed a mutation. It mutates the `Vector2` instance you call it on. `.pivot` is a getter. It gives you *a copy of* the `Vector2` used as a pivot. So your original code says "Take a copy of the pivot, set the copy to a new value, then discard the copy without ever modifying the original" — what you really want to do is assign to the original pivot, which is what the `=` operator does for you in your updated code.

Comment: So the `.pivot` gives a copy not a reference. Thank you.

Comment: This is the case in general for `struct` types in C#, which are value types rather than reference types.

Comment: Seriously look into the differences of structs and classes. It's quite important to know about them when working with C#. You might also want to create structs at some point. The main things to distinguish are mutable (normal classes) & immutable (strings) reference types and structs (int, TimeSpan, double).

Comment: Thanks @Battle yeah I've tried a view times with stuff like "When should I use a struct or class",  "struct vs class", "difference between" etc.  But from these resources I didn't appreciate the significance of "reference semantics"... I do now!  :) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521298/when-to-use-struct